# How to compile bitcoin source code with wallet?

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, compiling

I've built the bitcoin core on my computer and once I tried to run tests related to wallet, I encountered this error:

```
[amirreza@localhost bitcoin]$ python test/functional/wallet_createwallet.py 
2022-06-20T16:36:53.675000Z TestFramework (WARNING): Test Skipped: wallet has not been compiled.
2022-06-20T16:36:53.725000Z TestFramework (INFO): Stopping nodes
2022-06-20T16:36:53.725000Z TestFramework (INFO): Cleaning up /tmp/bitcoin_func_test_mnwvrnya on exit
2022-06-20T16:36:53.726000Z TestFramework (INFO): Test skipped
```

When I tried to reconfigure the compilation process by `./configure` I noticed it doesn't compile wallet:

```
Options used to compile and link:
  external signer = yes
  multiprocess    = no
  with experimental syscall sandbox support = yes
  with libs       = yes
  with wallet     = no
```

But I don't know how to change this option to compile with wallet. I took look at `./configure` options but see that it is enabled by default:

```
[amirreza@localhost bitcoin]$ ./configure --help
...
  --disable-wallet        disable wallet (enabled by default)
...
```

Comment: Did you install the wallet dependency (sqlite3)?

Comment: @MichaelFolkson not sure, but first I should find a way to compile the `wallet` then get errors for not satisfying the dependencies and try to fix them.

Comment: You need to have installed sqlite3 before you try to build Core with the wallet.

Comment: The `./configure` autodetection script will automatically disable wallet support if it notices you're missing wallet dependencies. Installing sqlite3 (for newer-style descriptor wallets) and/or bdb (for older-style legacy wallets) is likely all that is missing.

Comment: @MichaelFolkson I didn't get any error for this. I'll install it and retry.

Comment: @PieterWuille thanks, I try it.